# Wix Installer - Custom Action for updating appsettings.json (.net core3.1)

Tags: .net-core, wix, custom-action

I have created .Net core Web API application which will be self-hosted on a local machine and one configuration utility to update the API application configurations.

There is one key in appsetting.json (IN API Project), which returns the absolute path for the other projects configuration file.

```
{
    "ConfigFilePath": "<INSTALL DIRECTORY>\\..\\ConfigurationApplication\\Configuration\\ActualConfig.json"
}
```

I have created the MSI installer using WIX (I am new to WIX Installer) and integrated both the projects into one product and used *WixUI_InstallDir* to get the installation directory from the user.

I want to update the appsettings.json, ConfigFilePath value pointing to the installation directory which the user has selected.

Through some googling, I have found that it can be achieved by CustomAction in WIX.

But What my questions are,

1. WIX Custom action project is created in the .net framework, So If I create the CustomAction Project and refer the same into the installer, Will it required the .net framework dependency on the installer machine?
2. Is there any alternative to update the appsettings.json of .net core application from WIX?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. WIX Custom action project is created in the .net framework, So If I create the CustomAction Project and refer the same into the installer,
>    Will it required the .net framework dependency on the installer
>    machine?

Yes, if your custom action is written in .NET, it will require .NET to run.

> 2. Is there any alternative to update the appsettings.json of .net core application from WIX?

The [WixJsonExtension](https://github.com/NerdyDuck/WixJsonExtension) is written in C++ and doesn't require .NET to be installed on the target machine.